# How to get deleted orders (trashed) in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I am trying to get the trash order list from WooCommerce Shop Order. Previously i tried with Order Status to Publish it return properly for my needs. Now in the WooCommerce Version 2.2+ they added the Post Status as wc-completed something. In this case i cannot get the trash post.

I tried as something like

```
function gettrashedorderlist() {
$args = array('post_type'=>'shop_order','posts_per_page'=>'-1','post_status'=>array('trash'));

foreach(get_posts($args) as $eachorder) {
// Something goes here 
}
}
```

With latest version i unable to get the trashed order list.  I also tried as something like

```
 function gettrashedorderlist() {
    $args = array('post_type'=>'shop_order','posts_per_page'=>'-1','post_status'=>array('wc-completed'));

    foreach(get_posts($args) as $eachorder) {
    // Something goes here 
    }
    }
```

It is working but in this case i get a serious trouble because it displays all the orders including trashed order list. Not sure if something i made wrong or i understood wrong.

Ideally when i trying the post status as wc-completed instead of listing all those order including that i trashed, it should show excluding the trashed order.

Is that any way to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you passing an array to `'post_status'`? You should just be able to use `'post_status' => 'trash'`

Comment: Can you please select a correct answer? It's best not to leave Stack Overflow questions open. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be passing a string, not an array, to `'post_status'`:

```
function gettrashedorderlist() {
    $args = array('post_type'=>'shop_order','posts_per_page'=>'-1','post_status'=>'trash');

    foreach(get_posts($args) as $eachorder) {
        // Something goes here 
    }
 }
```